# Converting NSData from an Alamofire POST Request to String variables

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to convert the NSData returned from an alamofire POST request to a string variables. When I try to perform this action using JSONSwifty, all I receive are nil values and errors.

I need to just get the user_id as a string value from the response.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://api.trimitapp.co.uk/v1/user", parameters: ["data": parameter!])
            .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
            .response{ (request, response, data, error) in

                print(request)
                print(response)
                print(data)
                print(error)
                print("\n\n")

                let info = JSON(data: data!)


                guard let items = info["user"]["user_id"].string else{
                    print("error")
                    return
                }
                print(items)
        }
    } catch{}
```

This is the NSData I receive from the POST Request:

```
{
    "user": {
       "user_id": 64,
       "account": {
          "account_id": 92
       }
    }
}
```

I am using the Alamofire and SwiftyJSON frameworks.

Comment: The error parameter is nil

Comment: Does the `error` parameter print something?

Comment: `user_id` seems to be not a string, try `.int`

Comment: @vadian I tried that as well and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Rob When I try that, it gives me this error - Cannot convert value of type 'Response<AnyObject, NSError>' to expected argument type 'NSData'

Comment: Replacing `response` method with `responseJSON` (which takes one parameter rather than four) obviates need for SwiftyJSON. See https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-handling

Comment: @Rob This code gives me a nil value: 
                    
                    '.responseJSON{(data) in
                    
                    let information = data.result.value
                    let info = JSON(information!)
                    
                    print(info["user"]["user_id"].string)
                }'

Comment: @Rob I've removed the line let info = JSON(information) and it works now. I think it was because it was already a JSON Object and that function was returning it into a JSONObject of a JSONObject.Thank you.